Can I make Pygame rectangle outline with two different color?

if(blueBoxX!=redBoxX or blueBoxY!=redBoxY):
    pygame.draw.rect(scrn, (0, 100, 255), (blueBoxX*75, blueBoxY*75, 75, 75), 3)
    pygame.draw.rect(scrn, (255, 100, 0), (redBoxX*75, redBoxY*75, 75, 75), 3)
else:
    "when they collide I want it to show by showing two colors at one spot"

I was thinking of using just straight line by pygame.draw.line but wanted to know if pygame.draw.rect was possible option

No. pygame.draw.rect()  has only one color and does not have the option of drawing only some sections or sides of the outline. I suggest to use pygame.draw.lines():
x, y = blueBoxX, blueBoxY
l1 = [(x*75, y*75 + 75), (x*75, y*75), (x*75 + 75, y*75)]
l2 = [(x*75, y*75 + 75), (x*75 + 75, y*75 + 75), (x*75 + 75, y*75)]
pygame.draw.lines(scrn, (0, 100, 255), False, l1, 3)
pygame.draw.lines(scrn, (255, 100, 0), False, l2, 3)



No, pygame.draw.rect is a single color.
As everything in programming, the usual way is to define your own functions to perform your tasks. Pygame's rect call itself is not far from that - for drawing   rectangle outlines it can very well be making four calls to .line internally as far as we know. (it is probably optimized, and line code is reused at some other level, but the effect for whoever is calling .rect from Python is the same)
So, onto your function:
from functools import partial

def colorrect(surface, colors, start_pos, width_height, width=1):
    if len(colors) != 2:
       raise TypeError("Please pass in 2 colors for drawing this rect")
       # you should specialize this so that your function can accept from 1 to 4 colors instead
    # pre-calculate the four corners coordinates:
    c1 = start_pos
    c2 = start_pos[0] + width_height[0], start_pos[1]
    c3 = start_pos[0] + width_height[0], start_pos[1] + width_height[1]
    c4 = start_pos[0], start_pos[1] + width_height[1]
    # alias the line function and pre-fill some parameters so we can type less:
    line = partial(pygame.draw.line, surface=surface, width=width)
    line(color=colors[0], start_pos=c1, end_pos=c4)
    line(color=colors[0], start_pos=c1, end_pos=c2)    
    line(color=colors[1], start_pos=c2, end_pos=c3)
    line(color=colors[1], start_pos=c3, end_pos=c4)

colorrect((scrn, [(0, 100, 255), (255,100, 0)], (blueBoxX*75, blueBoxY*75, 75, 75), 3)

now you can use this colorrect function instead of pygame.draw.rect. I suggest you explore ways of improving it.
